# regex in python: how to use variable string in pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I can match a string from a list of string, like this:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for key in keys:
    if re.search(key, line):
       break
```

the problem is that I would like to match a pattern made from regular expression + string that I would specify. Something like this:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for key in keys:
    if re.search('[^\[]'+key+'[^\]]', line):
       break
```

but this does not work (in this example I would like to match 'a', 'b' and 'c' only if they appear in squared brackets).
I think this has to do with raw strings etc, but I cannot find a way to make it work. Suggestions?

EDIT:

let's say I want to match a pattern a bit more complicated:

```
'[^\s*data\.'+key+'\s*=\s*\[(.+)[^\]]'
```

in order to match the number in brackets:

```
 data.a =  [12343.232 ]
```

Comment: Then use `re.search(r'\[{}]'.format(key), line)`. Or `if r'[{}]'.format(key) in line:`. See https://ideone.com/UimIyJ

Comment: "... I would like to match [...] if they appear in squared brackets" Then why have you negated the square brackets?

Comment: what about if I want to match something more complicated? like in the edit I have made

Comment: What edit do you mean? Please provide a test case.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because I want to match only what appears in the brackets

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/bVDxvr - I think you want to match `a` only when inside brackets. In `data.a =  [12343.232 ]`, it is outside, thus, no match is expected, right? And you want to match `a` inside `[data.a] =  12343.232`?

Comment: That's not what negation does.

Comment: The pattern from your update is very strange. Please make your question clearer, add more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you are right! I took the wrong pattern, but how do i match only the content in the brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.search('\['+re.escape(key)+']', line):
```

this will match `[key]`. Note that `re.escape` was added to prevent that characters within `key` are interpreted as regex.

Comment: You do not need to escape `]`.

Comment: Thank for the hint, but, are you sure? What if key=abc, then the regex would be '[abc]' witch matches any a, b, or c? What do I miss here?

Comment: No, the `[` must be escaped, and `]` does not have to.